# Keeps Resulting to a Zero?

Tags: vb.net

I need some help in my vb.net class. My assigned project is to make a program that will average 10 numbers. I tried to write it to the best of my abilities but I keep getting zero as a result. Please help me average 10 numbers.

```
Module Module1
Sub Main()
    Dim One As Integer
    Dim Two As Integer
    Dim Three As Integer
    Dim Four As Integer
    Dim Five As Integer
    Dim Six As Integer
    Dim Seven As Integer
    Dim Eight As Integer
    Dim Nine As Integer
    Dim Ten As Integer
    Dim A As Integer
    Dim B As Integer
    B = One + Two + Three + Four + Five + Six + Seven + Eight + Nine + Ten
    A = B / 2
    Console.WriteLine("Enter The First Number")
    One = Console.ReadLine()
    Console.WriteLine("Enter The Seconed Number")
    Two = Console.ReadLine()
    Console.WriteLine("Enter The Third Number")
    Three = Console.ReadLine()
    Console.WriteLine("Enter The Fourth Number")
    Four = Console.ReadLine()
    Console.WriteLine("Enter The Five Number")
    Five = Console.ReadLine()
    Console.WriteLine("Enter The Six Number")
    Six = Console.ReadLine()
    Console.WriteLine("Enter The Seven Number")
    Seven = Console.ReadLine()
    Console.WriteLine("Enter The Eight Number")
    Eight = Console.ReadLine()
    Console.WriteLine("Enter The Nine Number")
    Nine = Console.ReadLine()
    Console.WriteLine("Enter The Ten Number")
    Ten = Console.ReadLine()
    Console.WriteLine(B)
    Console.ReadKey()
End Sub
```

End Module

Comment: a) you cant sum the values before you collect them b) you have an arithmetic error - the average of 10 values is not `x/2`

Comment: VB, like many languages, is a *procedural* language. Statements are executed one after the other, in order, as a series of sequential instructions. You seem to be interpreting the assignment of `B = One + Two + ...` as a persistent functional relationship like, for example, a formula in an Excel spreadsheet. This is not the case. The value of `B` is here assigned only once using the present values of your other input variables (zero, because you have just declared them - VB is nice and initializes them to zero for you. Not all languages do). `B` retains this value until you assign to it again.

Comment: there is also no code there to print the result, just the sum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are assigning the value before reading the user input just change this to the end.

```
   B = One + Two + Three + Four + Five + Six + Seven + Eight + Nine + Ten
    A = B / 2
```